# Do products and/or coproducts exist in the category of closed algebraic sets?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

I was recently reading a [note](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hochster/615W10/supAG.pdf) by Mel Hochster where he introduces the category of closed algebraic sets over an algebraically closed field $K$ a ways down on page 6.

Out of curiosity, do products and/or coproducts exist in the category of closed algebraic sets?

Comment: It looks like he discusses finite products on page 11. Coproduct should just be disjoint union, although if he wants everything to be embedded in an affine space then you might have to write down a short argument. [Something like: if $X \subset \mathbb{A}^n$ and $Y \subset \mathbb{A}^m$ with, say, $n \geq m$, then embed the two in parallel hyperplanes in $\mathbb{A}^{n + 1}$.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, they do. Note, by the theorem at the bottom of page 7, that your category is dual to the category of reduced finitely generated $k$-algebras, so (if they exist) products and coproducts in fg reduced $k$-algebras are taken to coproducts and products in closed algebraic sets over $k$. Showing products and coproducts in fg reduced $k$-algebras exist should be easier, if only because its a category you are more familiar with. Just in case, here's the final answer:

> Coproducts in fg reduced $k$-algebras are tensor products over $k$, and products are the normal cartesian products. These translate into product of topological spaces and disjoint union for the underlying topological spaces in your category of closed algebraic sets.